# Prime elements of $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt5]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, prime-factorization

I was studying the Gaussian integers and I proved that every composite number in $\mathbb{N}$ is not a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. This is true because this ring is an Euclidean domain, and if $n=ab$ is composite then
$$\lambda(n)=\lambda(a)\lambda(b),$$
and $\lambda(a),\lambda(b)>1$ where $\lambda(\alpha)=\alpha\overline{\alpha}$. Basically I used the property that every irreducible is prime.

This same property is not valid in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt5]$ because for example $2$ is irreducible but is not prime, as $2$ divides $6=(1+i\sqrt5)(1-i\sqrt5)$ but $2$ does not divide either of the factors.

How could I prove that there is some composite number of $\mathbb{N}$ which is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i\sqrt5]$? Is it possible to list the primes of this ring?

Comment: recall that prime elements in *any* integral domain are always irreducible, so if you can show that an element is reducible then necessarily you will have that it is not prime

Comment: then exploit the fact that prime and irreducible elements are the same in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: (hence, if an element is not prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, it will be reducible in $\mathbb{Z}$, and so... what can you conclude about it in any ring containing $\mathbb{Z}$?)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom and so it is reducible in any ring containing $\mathbb{Z}$ and so it can not be prime. Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $\Bbb{N}\subset\Bbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$, any factorization of $n$ in $\Bbb{N}$ is also a factorization of $n$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$.

This relies on the fact that the ring extension $\Bbb{Z}\subset\Bbb{Z}[i\sqrt{5}]$ does not introduce any new units, as noted in the comments.

Comment: Thanks!! I have edited my question. Can I list the primes of this ring, or at least describe them?

Comment: You have to also note that none of the factors in $\mathbb N$ will become units in $\mathbb Z[i\sqrt{5}]$.

Comment: @Wojuwu You are right, I have made this explicit.